# Generating PDF file of open page - Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

One of my html templates, has several charts and information about a user.
What I want to be able to do, is on button click to generate PDF of that page.
So, the same exact view,design and data that it has, in a PDF.
Is there a way to do this in Spring ? 
What libraries are best ?

I have seen some examples, but they create a PDF out of data they give dynamically. And I just want to know if it's possible to generate pdf of the open page as it is.
How do I do this ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Which templte engine do you use? JSP, Thymeleaf, FreeMarker, Groovy?

Comment: I am using Thymeleaf. I'm sorry, I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a screenshot with [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html) and set the image to a canvas.

Then convert canvas to pdf using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

Comment: Thank you so much! Will try that right away :) Thanks!!

Comment: I'm sorry, but will this also render the charts that I have and the page layout with the styles it has ? Or only html ?